# Передать переменную из Event Listener в контроллер

Tags: laravel

Мне нужно собрать в EventListener'е массив данных (`\Illuminate\Cache\Events\CacheHit`), а где-нибудь в контроллере получить этот массив. 
Как это лучше организовать?

Answer (score 0):

Ну как вариант, передать в вызванное событие анонимный метод. А вообще EventListener не должен ничего возвращать. Ибо тогда это уже не событие а Job.